# How to get value of input as String if value is dynamic?

Tags: jsp

I want to pass the value of an Input Element where the User fills in his name to another jsp file, so that when the User presses the login button, home.jsp will include his name. Doing it with a predefined value works, doing it with jquery doesnt.I need the Input Element as it is since I want to check the credentials with elements of a database table (works already)

I tried creating another Input Element with a predefined value as a String both inside and outside of the first form. That works just fine.

login.jsp looks like this.
I hope this includes everything needed to solve the problem

```
<h3>User Login</h3>
            <hr>
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/demo/login-user">
                    <div class= "alert alert-danger">                           
                        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                            value="${user.name}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                            value="${user.password}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
                </div>
                </form>

<form action="home.jsp" method="post">
   <%
session.setAttribute("userId", "dave"); //dave should be the ${user.name} value
    %>
</form>
```

home.jsp

```
<body>
<%String userid = session.getAttribute("userId").toString(); %>
<h1>Hello, <%=userid%></h1>
</body>
```

Expected result is if the user puts in his (correct) credentials, the home.jsp page loads with "Hello, NAME".

**Edit**

Realised its not jquery, but Expression Language? Another thread suggest I work with 
    `request.getParameter("name");`
But that throws a nullpointer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a `Servlet` for mapping `/demo/login-user`.

In that servlet's `doPost` method call

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("userid", request.getParameter("name"));
```

this way you can use `session.getAttribute("userId")` in all your jsp files to get logged in user name.

And you should remove the last part (`<form action="home.jsp" method="post"> <% session.setAttribute("userId", "dave"); //dave should be the ${user.name} value %> </form>`)  from your `login.jsp`